# How to set resolution without xrandr?

Tags: manjaro, xrandr, i3, resolution

For some reason my screen starts with a random resolution that can be 1440x900 or 1280x800 so I've tried to make a startup script that always set the resolution to 1440x900 with xrandr, but doesn't work, and if I try to just use xrandr like:

```
xrandr -s 1440x900
```

in the terminal, nothing happens, and with other resolutions it seems like xrandr is overwriting something else.

I use manjaro with i3wm, but before I used KDE, and KDE have a tool to set the resolution that used to work (even before, the screen used to start with random resolution and I configured it manually but worked)

It's there another resolution tool beside xrandr that I could use?

More info:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5
GPU: Vega 11
Kernel: 5.6.12-1-MANJARO

*Update*
Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x 
axis y axis) 410mm x 260mm
   1440x900      59.90*+
   1280x800      59.90  
   1280x720      59.90  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? Can you post output of `xrandr`?

Comment: You may need to specify the output when using `xrandr`. As ArkadiuszDrabczyk suggested, you should post the output of xrandr.

Comment: thx for comment, already updated :)

Comment: Arkadiusz Drabczyk I know isn't working because I can notice the fonts are stretched, but randomly, I mean, with every start.

Comment: @fxndvi: `xrandr` says that 1440x900 is the currently selected mode

Comment: yes, but always says that, and I can see how the fonts in my terminal changes, and I have to change the font size to feel comfortable. sometimes to 9, sometimes to 10, also the things that supposed to be like perfectly circular, sometimes are perfectly circular and sometimes don't.

Comment: I mean, it always says 1440x900 but I really can notice that something is wrong. Anyway I know it's a very weird problem, so, is there another resolution tool beside `xrandr` or other thing I could do?